# Cannot post complex object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the function on my view:

```
function setMessengerState() {
    var serviceURL = $("#messenger-set-state-url").val();

    var data = {
        messengerState: g_messengerState,
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceURL,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
    });

    function successFunc(data, status) {
        console.log("saved");
    }

    function errorFunc(data, status) {
        console.log("failed?");
    }
}
```

This is how the `JSON.stringify(data)` is formated on Chrome debugger:

```
"{"messengerState":{"IsOpen":true,"ConversationStates":[{"PartnerId":"64c71990-9ddc-4967-8821-a8e5936560a3","IsEnabled":true},{"PartnerId":"64c71990-9ddc-4967-8821-a8e5936560a3","IsEnabled":true}]}}"
```

And this is the value of `$("#messenger-set-state-url").val()`:

```
"/Messenger/Messenger/SetMessengerState"
```

The controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SetMessengerState(MessengerStateInfo messengerState)
{
    var user = User.ApplicationUser();

    if (user == null)
        return null;

    bool success = await MvcApplication.Messenger.SetState(user, messengerState) != null;

    return Json(success, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

And, finally, this is `MessengerStateInfo` and `ConversationStateInfo`:

```
public class MessengerStateInfo
{
    public bool IsOpen { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConversationStateInfo> ConversationStates { get; set; }

    public MessengerStateInfo()
    {
        ConversationStates = new ConversationStateInfo[0];
    }
}

public class ConversationStateInfo
{
    public string PartnerId { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot find where I'm doing it wrong. The post never gets to the controller method. I tried before with basic (`string`) parameters and it works just fine, but it simply doesn't get through with complex objects.

Comment: This line `data : JSON.stringify(data),` should be `data : data,`

Comment: I think it should be ``data =g_messengerState``

Comment: Neither of those work.

Comment: use `[FromBody]` in  `public async Task<ActionResult> SetMessengerState([FromBody]MessengerStateInfo messengerState)`

Comment: I mean instead of ``var data = {messengerState: g_messengerState}``. It should be just ``var data = g_messengerState``

Comment: @Venky, apparently `[FromBody]` is a MVC 6 feature. I'm using MVC 5.
@YSJ same result.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino Maybe it would help to use `List<ConversationStateInfo> ConversationStates { get; set; }` instead of an interface (also there's no need to initialize it in the constructor).

Comment: `PartnerId` you defined as `string` but you are passing a `Guid` into it.  Try changing the `PartnerId` into `Guid`.

Comment: what's the error messge you get?

Comment: `jquery-2.1.4.js:8630 POST http://localhost:64518/Messenger/Messenger/SetMessengerState 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: It's actually an error on ``ConversationStates = new ConversationStateInfo[0];`` I got Collection is read-only error there. What do you try to do there?

Comment: I want to make sure the collection is always initialized.

Comment: Yes. Apparently having a constructor that sets a property blows everything up. Removing it solving the problem. Write an answer and I'll approve it. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino Initializing a property in the default constructor isn't necessarily bad (although completely unnecessary for collections), the fact that you make it an array that has fixed size (and size 0 too) is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for writing a detailed question that allows reproducing the problem.

The [model binder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) expects your `ICollection` to be writable, but arrays are not writable in this manner. Do a simple experiment:

```
ICollection<int> a = new int[0];
a.Clear();
```

A "Collection is read-only" exception will be thrown.

Now, how do you fix this. Change your `MessengerStateInfo` class definition to the following:

```
public class MessengerStateInfo
{
    public bool IsOpen { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConversationStateInfo> ConversationStates { get; set; }
}
```

Here we removed the constructor, which allows the model binder to create a new instance of `List<>` type. This one, of course will be read-write and the binding succeeds.

Here are relevant code snippets from the model binder source code. This one is from `System.Web.ModelBinding.CollectionModelBinder<TElement>` class:

```
protected virtual bool CreateOrReplaceCollection(ModelBindingExecutionContext modelBindingExecutionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, IList<TElement> newCollection)
{
    CollectionModelBinderUtil.CreateOrReplaceCollection<TElement>(bindingContext, newCollection, () => new List<TElement>());
    return true;
}
```

And this one is one is from `System.Web.ModelBinding.CollectionModelBinderUtil`:

```
public static void CreateOrReplaceCollection<TElement>(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, IEnumerable<TElement> incomingElements, Func<ICollection<TElement>> creator)
{
    ICollection<TElement> model = bindingContext.Model as ICollection<TElement>;
    if ((model == null) || model.IsReadOnly)
    {
        model = creator();
        bindingContext.Model = model;
    }
    model.Clear();
    foreach (TElement local in incomingElements)
    {
        model.Add(local);
    }
}
```

As you can clearly see from this code, if the collection not empty `Clear` method is called on it, which, in your case leads to an exception. If, on the other hand the collection is null, `new List<>` is executed which results in a brand new (writable) object.

*Note: implementation details may differ depending on software version. The code above may differ from the actual code in the version of the library that you are using. The principle remains the same though.*

Here is a tip how to find the reason faster than typing the question to Stackoverflow.

Put a breakpoint on `public async Task<ActionResult> SetMessengerState(MessengerStateInfo messengerState)` and observe that the breakpoint is not hit. Open chrome console and take notion of the error icon.

[image]

Click on the icon to see the error message at the bottom.
Now click on then link in the error message, you'll see this screen:

[image]

Finally click on the request in the "Name" column. You will see this:

[image]

This gets you the actual error message with the stack trace. In most cases you will be able to tell what's wrong from this message. In this particular case you will immediately see that an array is tried to be cleared and fails.

Comment: Awesomely complete answer. Keep that up.

Answer (score 0):

The error is actually modifying `ICollection<ConversationStateInfo>` object in `ConversationStates = new ConversationStateInfo[0];`

Changing it to List should solve the issue.

Comment: Actually initializing it was the problem. You can use `ICollection`, `IEnumerable` or a plain array and it will work all the same as long as you don't initialize it.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino yeah. ``ConversationStates = new ConversationStateInfo[0];`` basically says it's a zero element collection, so it won't take your post data anymore. If you really want to always initialize this member, try data structure like list.

Answer (score 0):

Set $.ajaxSettings.traditional to true. I already have the same problem, and works for me

```
$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

 $('#btn').click(function () {
     var array = [];
     var url = '/Controller/Action';
     $.post(url, { array : array });
   });
 });
```